# Prevent any kind of connection to data store during Controler/Action context on ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have implemented Virtual Views for developers to play around with our framework in Asp.Net, something like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) "try it yourself" but with razor syntax.

The problem now is that I **need to prevent users to perform any kind of queries to the datastore**, or otherwise they would just retrieve all information they want.

Is there a way to prevent it on the Action context?

Relevant code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public async Task<PartialViewResult> VirtualView(string view)
{
    //code comes in view parameter
    //where user can create a context to connect to store
    //example: 
    //var db = new DbContext();
    //db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(); //will work
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(view);
    //(...) store bytes in a file
    return PartialView(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("fileName"));
}
```

Removing input validation means users can just create a connection to store and do whatever.

Comment: you means want to do some access rights control?

Comment: @winson forbid all queries

Comment: sorry, can you show some sample what the kind of queries? for your case, I can't find any connections with database?

Comment: @Winson - Edit: on the view parameter codes arbitrary code that the user writes